# Slick carousel out of memory

Tags: javascript, php, out-of-memory, slick.js

I am having memory issues using the plugin [slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).
I created a simple website in using .php files. I have 3 pages and one slider on each of them.
The browser struggles to load the pages after a few interaction with the slider and I get the following error in the console 'Uncaught out of memory'. I am not an expert in javascript nor in memory leaks. If someone could help me understand the problem, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Here is my main javascript file for the entire website:

```
 // on index.php
<div class="slider one">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>

 // on page2.php
<div class="slider one">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>

 // on page3.php
<div class="slider one">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>

//I cannot share the source code for legal reasons but basically this is the html stucture. On the actual project, I use images.


 var opt1 = {

  dots: false,

  infinite: true,

  slidesToShow: 4,

  slidesToScroll: 1,

  speed: 300,

  variableWidth: true,

  arrows: true,

  prevArrow: $('[data-prev="prevButton"]'),

  nextArrow: $('[data-next="nextButton"]'),

  responsive: [

    {

      breakpoint: 769,

      settings: {

        slidesToShow: 2,

        slidesToScroll: 1,

      }

    },

  ]

  }

var opt2 = {

  dots: false,

  infinite: true,

  slidesToShow: 1,

  slidesToScroll: 1,

  speed: 300,

  arrows: true,

  prevArrow: $('[data-prev="prevButton"]'),

  nextArrow: $('[data-next="nextButton"]')

}

var opt3 = {

  dots: false,

  infinite: false,

  slidesToShow: 3,

  slidesToScroll: 0,

  speed: 300,

  arrows: false,

  centerMode: false,

  variableWidth: true,

  prevArrow: $('[data-prev="prevButton"]'),

  nextArrow: $('[data-next="nextButton"]'),

  responsive: [

    {

      breakpoint: 1197,

      settings: {

        infinite: true,

        slidesToShow: 2,

        slidesToScroll: 1,

        centerMode: false

      }

    },

    {

      breakpoint: 769,

      settings: {

      slidesToShow: 2,

      slidesToScroll: 1,

      }

    },

    {

      breakpoint: 761,
        settings: {

        slidesToShow: 1,

        slidesToScroll: 1,

      }

    }

  ]

}

$(document).ready(function(){
 var gadgetCarousel = $(".slider");

 gadgetCarousel.each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(".one")) {
    $(this).slick($(opt1));
  } 
  else if ($(this).is(".two")){
    $(this).slick($(opt2));
   }
  else if ($(this).is(".three")){
   $(this).slick($(opt3));
 }
 else {
  $(this).slick();
  }
 })
}
```

Comment: Try playing around with the chrome performance tools, you may not understand exactly what you're looking at, but it might help understand what's happening

Comment: care to paste your markup?

Comment: I added the html

Comment: Is it possible that you are including the jQuery or Slick JavaScript libraries more than once on each page?

Comment: no, because I called the script in my footer.php which is included on every page

Answer (score 2):

I changed the value of the option 'slidesToScroll' from 0 to 3 and the 3rd slider works fine.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I can't believe this was the fix